# Data Vault Modelling Hub and Link

Tags: data-vault

I'm a beginner to data vault modeling and I'm asking for help.
What is the practice of modeling the essence "Document Status"?

```
create table DocumentStatus (
    period timestamp,
    documentid bigint references documents (documentid),
    status bigint,
    primary key (period, documentid)
)
```

Is it a link or a hub?
If this is a link, then what about period?
If this is a hub, then what about documentid?